# Cron jobs not working

Tags: xml, magento

Cron Job does not work, what am I doing wrong? My config.xml is below, I have 2 methods in my 'Kodework_Ongoing_Model_Observer' class.
The first method works perfectly on checkout, the cron job method dose not produce any entry to my log.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <kodework_ongoing>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    
        </kodework_ongoing>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>kodework_ongoing</module>
                    <frontName>ongoing</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
        <events>
   <sales_order_place_before>
    <observers>
     <Kodework_Ongoing_Observer>
     <type>singleton</type>
     <class>Kodework_Ongoing_Model_Observer</class>
     <method>ProcessOrder</method>
     </Kodework_Ongoing_Observer>
    </observers>
   </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
  
 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <Kodework_Ongoing_cron>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>Ongoing/observer::DoSomething</model></run>
            </Kodework_Ongoing_cron>
        </jobs>
 </crontab>

 </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: `<Kodework_Ongoing_corn>`...

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab node should not be within `<frontend>`, it should just be within `<config>`.  Additionally, I'd probably look at including your namespace, just for readbility.

`<config>
...
    <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <Kodework_Ongoing_cron>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>kodework_ongoing/observer::DoSomething</model></run>
        </Kodework_Ongoing_cron>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
...
</config>`

Also, might be worth installing [AOE Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) as this will give you visibility of the cron being available to the system.